# Difference Between AsyncResult and Task in c#

Tags: c#, async, io

So, in C#, I understand the historical difference between the two vaguely; a Task is a newer concept and the highest level concurrency native C# offers.

AsyncResult is a bit more ambiguous. For example, the docs say BeginRead relies on the underlying stream for non blocking behavior.

I know ReadAsync creates a Task which is handled by a Scheduler on the ThreadPool and therefore is guaranteed to not block, but then I read about C# delegates and Begin/EndInvoke which allow "any synchronous method to be asynchronous"

Is this true? As the documentation around BeginRead seems to indicate it still blocks if the underlying stream blocks. Is this equivalent to creating a Task, just less developer friendly?

Is a Task always preferred to an AsyncResult? Why or why not?

I surely hope this is the correct place to ask this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know ReadAsync creates a Task which is handled by a Scheduler on the ThreadPool and therefore is guaranteed to not block, but then I read about C# delegates and Begin/EndInvoke which allow "any synchronous method to be asynchronous"
>
> Is this true?

Yes, `ReadAsync` will not block, and yes, it will use the thread pool.

And yes `delegate.BeginInvoke` and `delegate.EndInvoke` will not block either. And yes, they use the thread pool. *And you should avoid them. Please have a look at [Difference between delegate.BeginInvoke and using ThreadPool threads in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340871/difference-between-delegate-begininvoke-and-using-threadpool-threads-in-c-sharp).*

---

> As the documentation around BeginRead seems to indicate it still blocks if the underlying stream blocks. Is this equivalent to creating a Task, just less developer friendly?

`Stream.BeginRead` is virtual. The class that derives from `Stream` can mess with it. So it *might block on some streams*. It should not be a problem for IO stream. However, the reference source for `Stream` also suggest that some platform could use blocking streams if they do not support async IO.

---

> Is a Task always preferred to an AsyncResult? Why or why not?

Yes.

`AsyncResult` is a promise, kind of like how `Task` is a promise. Except, it is worse.

An `AsyncResult` could be completed synchronously, or asynchronously. *Kind of like `Task`.* But if the `AsyncResult` did not complete synchronously, you get a `WaitHandle` (`AsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle`). And that means you will either have to pool or block on a thread to to wait on it...

Or do you? You can use `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to wait on the `WaitHandle` from the `AsyncResult`.

Add to that that `AsyncResult` does not express cancellation nor timeout by itself. You can specify your timeout to wait on the `WaitHandle`... but for cancellation you might be forced to create another `WaitHandle` for the cancellation then use `WaitHandle.WaitAny`... and of course handle the end method appropriately.

Finally, `AsyncResult` is the promise producer facing API, `IAsyncResult` is the promise consumer facing API. Because of this, you probably don't want to expose any `AsyncResult` in your API, only expose `IAsyncResult` if anything.

I would advice against using `AsyncResult` at all. If you use `AsyncResult`, messing with the producer is just a cast appart.

Of course, `Task` is better.

Comment: I was mistaken, I meant to say IAsyncResult the entire time, but this explanation makes sense. I was specifically wondering about the differences between Stream.BeginRead and Stream.ReadAsync. is it safe to say one handles a higher concurrent load than the other? i.e. if I want to make an application that makes thousands of arbitrary reads concurrently, would one perform better or is the difference mostly just in code?

Comment: @user1538301 hmm... I would argue that `BeginRead` is lower level, you probably can built something for such use case which is more performant by avoiding some unnecessary overhead (I would have to actually try and benchmark). It is, of course, harder to use, and thus it will be easier to introduce bugs using `BeginRead`. Which means that, as developer, you will be less productive. Now, it is economics.

Comment: @user1538301 thinking about it, using `BeginRead` and `EndRead` wil  likely result in more unmanaged resources (`WaitHandle`), while `Task` would avoid those.

Comment: I shall benchmark it and find out. Thanks